# Telegram BOT send special charactes

Tags: php, special-characters

I create a PHP script that send messages at Telegram BOT,

```
$postFields = array(
    'chat_id' => $chatId,
    'text' => $messageText,
    'reply_markup' => $encodedKeyboard
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, URL . TOKEN . '/sendMessage');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postFields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,  PROXY_HOST . ":" . PROXY_PORT);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD,  DOMAIN . "\\" . USERNAME . ":" . PASSWORD);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I can send bold, italic, underline and other style but I can't send correctly à, è, é, ì, ù characters.

Comment: Paste the code you're using to send the messages. Surely it will be a problem related to charset.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the **parse_mode** parameter with either markdown or html.

Set the `parse_mode` to `markdown` and send `*bold*`

Set the `parse_mode` to `html` and send `<b>bold</b>`